# How to remove one message from a pair?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Sender   Recipient NumMessages
-----------------------------
Vasya    Petya    1
Petya    Vasya    2
Eugen    Petya    3
Petya    Eugen    1
Masha    Sveta    5
```

How can I convert this kind of table to a one where I would have only a single record from any of pairs which also would have sum of NumMessages field for the pair ? It is of no matter which record from a pair to choose.
These gonna be the edges of undirected graph.

I need this:

```
Node1    Node2    NumMessages
-----------------------------
Vasya    Petya    3
Eugen    Petya    4
Masha    Sveta    5
```

I have uniqueidentifier type Ids for Sender/Recipient fields in my actual table if it can be used.
I tried to join this table to itself and count sum of NumMesages but how can leave just a single record out of a pair then ?

Thanks a lot

Slava

Comment: Can you show complete table defenition, with "uniqueidentifier type Ids" for Sender/Recipient?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot, just sender and recipient are from the same table where they have guid Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option using `case` ordering by the name:

```
select node1, node2, sum(nummessages)
from (
    select case when sender < recipient then sender else recipient end as node1,
            case when sender < recipient then recipient else sender end as node2,
           nummessages
    from yourtable
) t
group by node1, node2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need generate/find shared key for records where sender and recipient are same pair.

```
SELECT data.Id, SUM(data.NumMessage)
FROM (
SELECT CONCAT(Sender, Recipient) AS Id, NumMessages
FROM MessagePair
WHERE Sender > Recipient

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT(Recipient, Sender) AS Id, NumMessages
FROM MessagePair
WHERE Sender < Recipient
) data
GROUP BY data.Id
```